# Twig: get key of subarray without looping?

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

My Twig template is receiving an array that contains a path to an image file.  It looks like this:

```
array:1 [
  "path/to/images/images.jpg" => array:4 [
    "name" => "image.jpg"
    "type" => "image/jpeg"
    "size" => 77789
    "path" => "path/to/images/image.jpg"
  ]
]
```

You can see that the key of the subarray is being dynamically set to the actual path of the file.  I can't access that array because I don't know that key beforehand.  I know I can loop through the parent array to get any values from the subarray, but that seems messy.  So my question is: is there any way, in Twig, that I can extract the key of the subarray (the path) without looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the context surrounding the variable that you've shared, **but**...

Given a variable like the one in your question, I would access the path by utilizing the `first` filter in twig.

This assumes that your variable with the dynamically generated key is always being returned in the same, array-inside-a-one-item-array form:

```
{% set img = var | first %}
<img src="{{ img.path }}" />
// <img src="path/to/images/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Nice.  But what's your concern about "the context surrounding the variable"?

Comment: Concern's in the third sentence: "This assumes that your variable with the dynamically generated key is always being returned in the same, array-inside-a-one-item-array form"... to paraphrase - can you count on the variable being passed to the template always being in this form?